# Quickbooks create a TimeActivity

Tags: swift, httprequest, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

How can I make a POST request to create a time activity for my company on Quickbooks from a mobile app? I've got authorisation working fine, now I just need to know how to create items. For the HTTPBody of the request, what should I enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL(string:”Some Fancy URL“)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
var err: NSError?

var bodyData = “myBodyKey=myBodyValue“ as NSString
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

This is (a way) of setting the HTTPBody of a request

In regards to Quickbooks, they have a [api documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/timeactivity) regarding the time activity.

They explain here how to send a JSON Create Request.
And use as example

```
{
    "TxnDate":"2013-01-28",
    "NameOf":"Vendor",
    "VendorRef":{
        "value":"61"
    },
    "CustomerRef":{
        "value":"60"
    },
    "DepartmentRef":{
        "value":"3"
    },
    "ItemRef":{
        "value":"4"
    },
    "ClassRef":{
        "value":"100100000000000321202"
    },
    "BillableStatus":"Billable",
    "Taxable":true,
    "HourlyRate":251,
    "BreakHours":1,
    "BreakMinutes":0,
    "StartTime":"2013-01-28T08:00:00-08:00",
    "EndTime":"2013-01-28T17:00:00-08:00",
    "Description":"Single activity time sheet",
    "domain":"QBO",
    "sparse":false
}
```

As A data you would need to create a dictionary and encode this as json.

Comment: I know, but I need to know the body key for the request.

Comment: @GabrielJones, Edited (and I hope improved) the answer